# How do I trigger a Cognito logout when it's integrated with an ALB?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-net

I am currently using an AWS application load balancer to handle the authentication of my application, using Cognito and a user pool.

I can login just fine and acquire the relevant information; `X-Amzn-Oidc-Accesstoken`,`X-Amzn-Oidc-Identity` and `X-Amzn-Oidc-Data`.

Using the access token I can then decode and authenticate the user accordingly in my .NET 6 application.

However on log off, I start by revoking my tokens using `AdminUserGlobalSignOutAsync` in the AWS SDK (which works without error) -

```
var request = new AdminUserGlobalSignOutRequest
{
    UserPoolId = "my-userpool-id",
    Username = "username"
};
        
var response = await cognitoClient.AdminUserGlobalSignOutAsync(request);
```

I then tried to also clear relevant headers and cookies -

```
var headersToRemove = new List<string>
{
    "X-Amzn-Oidc-Accesstoken",
    "X-Amzn-Oidc-Identity",
    "X-Amzn-Oidc-Data"
};

foreach (var header in headersToRemove)
{
    if (Request.Headers.ContainsKey(header))
    {
        Request.Headers.Remove(header);
    }
}

foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
{
    Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
}
```

And finally redirect to the logout url -

```
https://{domain}.auth.{region}.amazoncognito.com/logout?response_type=code&client_id={clientid}&logout_uri={redirect_uri}&scope=openid
```

However on redirect I am landing on my application again, when I should be getting the Cognito login page.

I checked the browser and can see that the headers and cookies look to have been reinstated, and the only way I could land back on my application home page is if the ALB got the request, saw a valid token, and then let me through.

I found [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html#:%7E:text=Authentication%20logout,original%20authentication%20flow.) bit of documentation that states

> When an application needs to log out an authenticated user, it should set the expiration time of the authentication session cookie to -1 and redirect the client to the IdP logout endpoint

What am I missing for the tokens/cookies to not be revoked? I realise I am not dealing with a `refresh token` here as that is not sent back in the authentication headers after login. I also made sure that `Enable token revocation` is enabled in my app client.

Also the life span of refresh, id and access tokens in my client are all set to 1 day (even though I think the only one relevant here is the access token), however I thought this would be irrelevant after using the global sign out?

Comment: We meet again! I shall try this and let you know!

Comment: Once again you were correct Ermiya! Put an answer down and you can have it! Also check our old chat please. PS I had to add -     cookiesToDelete.Add("AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0");
cookiesToDelete.Add("AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-1");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To logout from Cognito when using ALB integrated auth, you need to trigger a delete of the `AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-X` cookies generated by the ALB from your server-side code i.e. at the target.**

You can do this by creating new already-expired cookies via the [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header with the same names as the cookies generated by the ALB e.g. `AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0` and `AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-1`<sup>1</sup>. You can set the values to anything (though the norm is to set it to nothing).

To then mark them as already expired, set the [`Expires`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#expiresdate) attribute to any timestamp in the past or alternatively, as the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html#authentication-logout) vaguely point to, set the [`Max-Age`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#max-agenumber) attribute to 0 or a negative number like -1. Note that `Max-Age` takes precedence over `Expires`. Either way, the cookies will be marked as expired.

You're on the right track. [`IResponseCookies.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iresponsecookies.delete?view=aspnetcore-7.0) *does* expire cookies by creating a new cookie with the name provided, sets the `Expires` attribute (see source code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http/src/Internal/ResponseCookies.cs#L163)) to `Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT` and add it as a `Set-Cookie` header.

However, the ALB doesn’t actually return the `AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-X` cookie(s) to your backend, so it’s not in `Request.Cookies`. As a result, when you enumerate `Request.Cookies.Keys`, it doesn’t include `AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-X`, and .NET never creates the `Set-Header` headers for your (new & expired) `AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-X` cookies.

Also, `Request.Headers` is the collection of headers sent by the client. It's futile to do `Request.Headers.Remove(header);` as changing it (post-retrieval on the server-side) does nothing. It'd just be removing data from a collection that was populated purely for read-only purposes. And as a side-note, your request cookies would be under the `Cookie` header and stored within `Request.Cookies`.

All in all, you just need to manually specify the cookie names to be set as expired.

This should work:

```cs
var cookiesToExpire = new List<string>
{
    "AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0",
    "AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-1"
};

foreach (var cookieName in cookiesToExpire)
    Response.Cookies.Delete(cookieName);
```

The API will then return headers that look like this:

```
Set-Cookie: AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/;
Set-Cookie: AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-1=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/;
```

Finally, as per [RFC 6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265) section 5.3, the client will then:

1. delete the old cookie(s)
2. add the new cookie(s)
3. delete the new cookie(s), since the new cookie(s) are expired

> A cookie is "expired" if the cookie has an expiry date in the past.
>
> The user agent MUST evict all expired cookies from the cookie store if, at any time, an expired cookie exists in the cookie store.

After deleting the cookies, redirect to the IDP logout endpoint to complete the logout.

---

Unfortunately, the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html#authentication-logout) on this isn't the most helpful. To prevent confusion for future users, I've submitted comprehensive feedback to AWS with my suggestions on how to improve the *'Authentication Logout'* section to be much clearer and practical regarding the steps needed to perform an ALB log out. I'll update this answer once the docs are hopefully updated.

---

<sup>1</sup> *There might be multiple cookies here and there's nothing (yet) in the docs on how many so please double check - there might be more than just 2.*

Comment: Spot on and worked like a treat good job!